# Assign widget value in spark sql statement

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, widget, databricks

How do I add the value which I entered in the widget in our spark sql statement

```
it_flex_range = dbutils.widgets.get("it_flex_range")
iv_werks=dbutils.widgets.get("Plants")
```

How do I add the above value which I got from the widget in the below statement

```
mt_flex_1= spark.sql("select * from table name where flexcell = lit(dbutils.widgets.get("it_flex_range") and werks = lit(dbutils.widgets.get("iv_werks")")
```

Comment: you could use the [`.format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) formatters

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spark-sql directly, you could follow the steps in the below link

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#using-widget-values-in-spark-sql

In case used in a python/pyspark code, you could use format() as suggested earlier or f-string...Since I do not have a table, just included them in the select statement...

```
dbutils.widgets.text("it_flex_range", "default_it_flex", label = "it_flex_range")
dbutils.widgets.text("Plants", "default_Plants", label = "Plants")
it_flex_range = dbutils.widgets.get("it_flex_range")
iv_werks=dbutils.widgets.get("Plants")
                    
mt_flex_1= spark.sql(f"select '{it_flex_range}', '{iv_werks}'")
mt_flex_1.show()
```

```bash
+---------------+--------------+
|default_it_flex|default_Plants|
+---------------+--------------+
|default_it_flex|default_Plants|
+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I see a PySpark example on medium from Robert Chynoweth (Converting Stored Procedures to Databricks)  where the object in the curly brackets is not using the quotes.  Are you using the quotes here as a means of converting them to text?

Comment: I went through the post, it was very useful - you are right, within the PySpark code,  widgets ideally get returned as string which are quoted. I just remember it as how it would show up if it were to come in a SQL statement. e.g. `%sql SELECT '1', 2` 1 is a string whereas 2 is an integer.